# Xcode: how to test my app on older versions of iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

I would like to test my app on older versions of iOS. By "older versions" I mean iOS 5.1 5.0 and 4.3. In order to do so, what should I do in Xcode? I've already downloaded (through Xcode) all the corresponding simulators, but I don't know how to build and run my app on a specific simulator. The only choice I have is to run my app on iPhone/iPad 6.0 simulator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your applications deployment target is set to `iOS 6.0`. Make it to the lowest version you want. I believe iOS 4.3 is the lowest that is possible right now.

To change deployment target,

1. Select project file in Project Navigation
2. Click your target
3. In the summary tab, choose your deployment target.

**EDIT: After seeing @Abizern answer.**
Well I answered to this part in the question.

> The only choice I have is to run my app on iPhone/iPad 6.0 simulator.

OP was not getting older version of simulator to show up in the drop down menu. It was because his project base sdk target  and deployment target was set to `iOS 6.0`. By setting deployment target to a lower version, other simulators started to show up.

But as @Abizern correctly pointed out, to run on a simulator of lower version you have to choose the correct simulator from dropdown menu to run. Well just to make it clear.

Comment: It was incredibly easy! Thanks!

Comment: @pAkY88 If this answer helped you, you should accept it as solution.

Answer (score 10):

Both of these answers weren't clear enough, I'm adding this to stop people making incorrect assumptions.

The only way to test on a lower version of the iOS is to run it on a device with the lower version or on one of the lower version simulators.

The "Deployment Target", which both answers here incorrectly say runs the app on a lower version, just sets the minimum installed OS version that the app will run on. When you run it on the iOS 6 simulator - it is still running on the version 6, not to whatever your deployment target is set at.

But, without setting a lower deployment target, the option to use a different iOS Simulator isn't available.

Best practice is to build with the latest version and SDK available and set the deployment target to the lowest version that your app supports.

As for running the app on different versions of the simulator - have a look at the dropdown in the top left corner of Xcode - you can pick which of the installed simulators to run your app on from there.

Comment: Thanks Abizern! Actually I had understood that in order to test the compatibility of the app I should have run it on different simulators

Comment: Well @Abizem, you are correct about selecting simulator from the drop down menu to run. But OP's original problem was simulators other than iOS 6.0  were not showing up in the menu. For showing them you have to set a lower deployment target. Thanks I corrected my answer anyway..

Comment: ***The "Deployment Target", which both answers here incorrectly say runs the app on a lower version***  I really like to know where in my answer I am saying this. Just to make it clear ,the title of the question is not telling the actual problem OP had.

Answer (score 5):

Open Xcode and in the menu at the top left, where you select what device to run on, click "More Simulators..."

The download section of Xcode preferences will open,

Click the "Components" tab.

You will see a list of simulators that can be installed, click install on version you need.

The simulator will need to restart to install.

To run the newly installed version of the simulator just select it from the run menu in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

At the sidebar left, click on the first element of the list(usually is the name of your project). A new menu will open, like my screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Just select the target that you want to simulate.